# Error : Invalid auth/bad request (got a 401, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)

Tags: php, api, oauth, yahoo, yahoo-api

Why i got this error when i use following code?

```
$customer_key = 'my_key';
$customer_securet = 'customer_securet';                
$a = new Oauth($customer_key, $customer_securet, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATIONl);
$a->getRequestToken('https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token?oauth_callback=http://mysite.com/invitehandler.php?provider=yahoo');
```

Error : Invalid auth/bad request (got a 401, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)

Comment: That error usually means the OAuth request was not properly signed. Which OAuth library are you using? Also, it could be the the format of your request URL: the "?provider=yahoo" part should be "&provider=yahoo".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my problem myself..

Its just needed update server time!

Comment: How would I update the server clock? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @Brett: im using this code **ntpdate ro.pool.ntp.org** to update my server time.